# angular 2 wait untill DOM renders Masonry libary

Tags: javascript, angular

Hello I want to use Masonry jquery plugin with angular 2.
I load Data via service.

```
  loadAllNews (){
    this.loadingNews = true;
    this._dataService.getNews(1).first().subscribe(data=>{
      this.newsArray = data;
      this.showMoreNewsButton = false;
      this.updateColumnHeight();
    });
  }
```

Than I want to run function `updateColumnHeight()` to run Masonry  calculation.
Inside of function I run setTimeout to wait for DOM

```
private updateColumnHeight() {

setTimeout(()=>{
  let container = this._nativeElem.nativeElement.querySelector('.js-container');

  let msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    itemSelector: '.js-column-card',
    gutter: 10,

  });
  this.loadingNews = false;

},100)
```

Is there any way to wait until DOM ready or check it I try with `ngAfterViewChecked` but than it runs forever and I will end up with no memory problem.

Comment: If Masonry emits an event when it's done, you can listen to that. If not, then there is no way. You could use MutationObserver to wait for a specific change to happen and then emit an event there for Angular to listen or call a components method directly.

Comment: Try the `ngAfterViewInit` hook

Comment: For now i did in by $(document).ready......